# How to rigorously compare my String-Search algorithm against current benchmarks. Currently beating/equaling Boyer-Moore ~half the times in my test

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, comparison, string-search

A String Search algorithm I wrote is performing incredibly well in my own test, but I'd like to test it more rigorously to know how well it objectively performs. Anyone know of a resource I can use to run such tests?

The test I created puts together 5000 random words, then randomly picks one of those words as the 'pattern'. When I run my test 1000 times (each time with a new set of 5000 random words and a new 'pattern'), my algorithm beats (in speed) Boyer-Moore roughly 1/3 of the times, and beats/equals Boyer-Moore roughly 3/5 of the times.

When I take the average time of all 1000 tests, sometimes my algorithm has a better average, but more often Boyer-Moore has a better average, though usually not by much (<0.0005ms).

Here's how the comparison looks as a scatter plot for n=1000.The black lines compare the two algorithms for any specific set (blue marks are my algorithm times, orange are for Boyer-Moore). The red line compares the two averages over these n tests. Averages are written in the title.

[image]

So if you know of any resource that can help me test this, please send my way.

Thanks.

Comment: test at the peak points and increase limits from 5k to 500k (lets say), increase word length also , then test all the cases

Comment: It's not so easy to compare string search algorithms.  Even the simplest search performs well on random data.  Comparing worst-case performance is useful, but different algorithms have different worst cases.  You could try to test against "average" or "realistic" cases, but that is also not easy, since real-world uses of string search algorithms are so varied.

Comment: Also, since the complexities of comparable algorithms will be the same, you'll also be comparing the quality of the implementations.  It's important to use quality implementations, and you really can't produce a quality implementation in python.  Test your algorithm against python's built-in string search to see why.  The built-in will be many times faster.